# Retrieving last inserted iD then uploading to MySQL. #PDO #PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form that uploads *Textarea Information* and an *Image* to MySQL simultaneously.

The *Textarea* `iD` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` while the *Image* `iD` must be the `textarea's` copy. I've tried within the `$_POST` to get `lastInsertId()`; which returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined function lastInsertId()`.

This is my current code for the isset that uploads the information to the Function and/or query:

```
if(isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_FILES['photo1'])){
    $update = $_POST['update'];
    $data = $Wall->Insert_Update( $uiD, $update);

    $name       = $_FILES['photo1']['name'];
    $tmp_name   = $_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'];
    $target = "uploads/". $_FILES['photo1']['name'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$target)) {
        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT post_iD FROM posts WHERE uid_fk = :uiD");
        $sth->execute(array(':uiD' => $uiD));

        $post_iD = lastInsertId();
        $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user_uploads (image_path, uid_fk, image_id_fk) VALUES (:image_path, :uiD, :image_id_fk)');
        $sth->execute(array(':image_path' => $target, ':uiD' => $uiD, ':image_id_fk' => $post_iD));
    }
}
```

Here is the Insert_Update that is uploading the textarea:

```
PUBLIC FUNCTION Insert_Update( $uiD, $update){
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT post_iD,message FROM posts WHERE uid_fk = :uiD ORDER by post_iD DESC LIMIT 1");
$sth->execute(array(':uiD' => $uiD));

$result = $sth->fetch();

        if ($update!=$result['message']){

            $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts ( message, uid_fk, ip, created) VALUES ( :update, :id, :ip, :time)");
            $sth->execute(array(':update' => $update, ':id' => $uiD, ':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ':time' => time()));

            $sth = $this->db->prepare("
                                        SELECT M.post_iD, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.username 
                                        FROM Posts M, users U 
                                        WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uiD 
                                        AND M.uid_fk = ? 
                                        ORDER by M.post_iD DESC LIMIT 1");
            $sth->execute(array($uiD));

            $result = $sth->fetchAll();
            return $result;
            } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

FORM:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="update" id="update" class="_iType"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="photo1">
    <input type="submit" value="post" class="update_button"> 
</form>
```

More Information within the database which I doubt it'll be useful.

1. `posts table` : where the textarea information will be located.

   *post_iD | message | uid_fk | ip | created |*
2. `user_uploads table` : Where the image location will be located.

   *image_iD | image_path | uid_fk | image_id_fk*

NOTICE: `image_id_fk` should equal `post_iD` ( which is obvious ).

How is the `lastInsertId()`; suppose to be used?

**EDIT 1: After upload completes the inserted value for the image_id_fk equals 0, instead of the post_iD value. Any ideas for this reason?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used right after you **successfully** execute an `INSERT` statement. However, you have to always check whether the execution was successful (or are there affected rows) because there can be `last insert ID` from previously executed statement.

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts ( message, uid_fk, ip, created) VALUES ( :update, :id, :ip, :time)");
$sth->execute(array(':update' => $update, ':id' => $uiD, ':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ':time' => time()));

$this->db->lastInsertId(); //Upon success, is available
```

**For example:**
You have a function that creates a new post. This function on success can return the last insert ID value, so you can display that value to user. Like:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $manager->createPost($_GET['id']) ;
  if (is_numeric($id)){
    echo "Your article has been created. ID: {$id}" ; //Or link to it.
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Here is my suggestion to your problem: `lastInsertId always retuns 0`:

Your table, where you insert values, must have `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` field, preferrably with type `int`.

Comment: Thank you for being very detailed on that function. What if lastInsertId(); isn't retrieving any values at all, and uploading the value of 0 to the database? as that's what it's currently doing!

Comment: Do you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in your DB?

Comment: Not for the image_id_fk which that must equal the post_iD which does have AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Okey, you must have a unique `AUTO_INCREMENT` id for each item in your table.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in the thread itself. image_id_fk should equal the last inserted id so that I can retrieve the image within a loop.
textarea = post_iD. image = image_id_fk = post_iD. So they need to match, because they've been uploaded together. Even then, should I have AUTO_INCREMENT for the image_id_fk, wouldn't it have a different id value?

EDIT: you're right and it does have the auto increment but I'm just trying to match both id's so I can pull the data together in a loop.

Comment: I think your `image_ID` should be `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: image_iD has AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY KEY. Though that isn't the issue I'm having. EX: The issue is when I press the upload button, textarea gives an id of 333, and the image_id_fk gives an id of 0, I'd like the image_id_fk to match the textarea id, so that I may return both the textarea information and image together.

Comment: I am sorry, it is just a bit hard to figure out what you need :(

Comment: It's no problem at all, you helped most and I got it to work so I appreciate your help. You were correct tho, that was what I needed and it was a mistake of my part I just needed to delete a query that was useless.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing  [pdo lastinsertid](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) in wrong way. It requires database connection object.

```
$post_iD = lastInsertId();
```

should be

```
$post_iD = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: You are correct my good man. I forgot to mention when it does upload it always enters a value of 0 never the lastinsertiD value.

Comment: @iBrazilian Can you clarify this?

Comment: Of course.
Instead of inserting the lastInsertId(); it uploads the value of 0. As if lastInsertId(); wasn't retrieving any values at all. ON MySQL database, image_id_fk = 0 instead of ex: post_iD = 344 while image_id_fk = 0. Was that understandable?

Comment: @iBrazilian Before using `lastInsertId()` you are using select statement. So do you want the id of select statement?

Comment: Yes. That's the point, since I have a form and I'm uploading a a file and text information, I'd like both of them to have the same iD so that I can pull the information together. Or I'd like the LastInsertId() to return the same post_iD that the Insert_Update function is uploading.

Comment: @iBrazilian `lastInsertId` will give you auto increment id when the last executed sql query will be `INSERT` query, but as I can see you use `SELECT` query before using `lastInsertId` and because of that it gives you `0`.